# MYSQL Insert Sort Value From Subquery

Tags: mysql

I have the following MYSQL INSERT statement:

```
SET @x = 0;
INSERT INTO Table1 (col1, sortOrder, col3)
SELECT 'col1', (@x:=@x+1), col3 FROM Table2 WHERE col4 = XYZ ORDER BY col3
```

I want replace (@x:=@x+1) with the result from the following query which returns the next available number from sortOrder:

```
SELECT min( rank ) AS Num
FROM (SELECT num, @curRank1 := @curRank1 +1 AS rank
FROM (SELECT sortOrder AS num
FROM Table1 WHERE col4 = XYZ
UNION
SELECT sortOrder AS num
FROM Table1 WHERE col4 = XYZ)a1, (SELECT @curRank1 :=0) r
ORDER BY num ASC)tab
WHERE num != rank
```

Comment: Your current code won't even run.  Please show sample data which explains how you want `Table1` to look after the insert.

Comment: make sortOrder autoincrement and unique in db that will automatically pick next avaialble no. No need to put any logic while insert.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I've fixed the example - sorry about that.

Comment: @somsgod unfortunately there are multiple sets of data each with their own sortOrder which means we can't make the column autoincrement.

Comment: There is no in built sql function which can help you here and I cannot imagine a case where it would be useful, an expansion of the question to explain what you are trying to achieve would be interesting and might prompt an alternate approach. If you must do this then you are going to have to code for it yourself - if you have a front end technology (php?) you might want to do it there rather than in mysql.

Comment: @P.Salmon I've amended the question, hopefully this will yield a result